# Multiple synonym(s) for search terms

Tags: magento

I'm in need to have more than 1 synonym for a search term in magento (version 1.4.2.0 - can't upgrade it for now), but all my attempts to add multiple synonyms have failed.

I've been looking around without any solution, any of you had a similar need and managed to find a solution?

Thanks for any help,
Mat.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So you have people look for 'doodad' or 'dodad' and you want to show people the 'macguffin' instead.

So far you have tried to add these search terms in on the back-end but it has not worked.

The fix-workaround is surprisingly simple.

Type in 'dodad' in the frontend - no result given.

Now type 'doodad' in the frontend - again no results.

Now go into the backend and go to the last page of the search terms.

The entries for 'dodad' and 'doodad' will be in there. You can now put 'macguffin' in the synonym box.

Now go to the front and type in 'dodad' or 'doodad' into the search box and it will take you straight to the 'macguffin' item.

Comment: +1 for 'doodad' and 'macguffin' terminology. Who needs foo and bar anyway? :)

Comment: A MacGuffin is "a plot element that catches the viewers' attention or drives the plot of a work of fiction". The defining aspect of a MacGuffin is that the major players in the story are willing to do and sacrifice almost anything to obtain it, regardless of what the MacGuffin actually is. In fact, the specific nature of the MacGuffin may be ambiguous, undefined, generic, left open to interpretation or otherwise completely unimportant to the plot. Common examples are money, victory, glory, survival, a source of power, a potential threat, or it may simply be something entirely unexplained.

Comment: @B00MER The director and producer Alfred Hitchcock popularized both the term "MacGuffin" and the technique, with his 1935 film The 39 Steps, an early example of the concept.[5] Hitchcock explained the term "MacGuffin" in a 1939 lecture at Columbia University: "[We] have a name in the studio, and we call it the 'MacGuffin'. It is the mechanical element that usually crops up in any story. In crook stories it is almost always the necklace and in spy stories it is most always the papers" - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacGuffin - Please spread the meme!!!

Comment: @ʍǝɥʇɐɯ Thanks a lot man, I've come to this solution too just few minutes ago!